# NodeJS | How to send image from a socket server to an other server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

i'm working on a new project and i want to ask you about a problem I'm facing up.

I have a web server that run socket.io module. that server listen to its port (3012) and stream an image to client using socket.

I have my main server with a different port (4049). A frond end part of this server include a blank container.

I want to find a way to send from the Socket server to my main server the streamed image and my main server to listen as a new client every time.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is emit the chunks to the socket server everytime the `.on('data')` event is triggered on the image `Readable stream` on the client, and then when you receive the chunks you write them to a `Writeable Stream` on the websocket server side.

There are a few things to have in mind:

- You will need to detect the EOF on the server (checking for specific file type EOF bytes), or emit some sort of header from the client. Example.

```
const EOF = Buffer.alloc(6);

// Client Side

client.sendBytes(EOF); // on end

// Server
if(chunk.slice(-6).compare(EOF) === 0)
  console.log('File EOF close write stream');
```

- If you're reading multiple images at the same time, you will need to add an identifier to each chunk to correctly write to on the server side. The identifier should have always the same length, so you can slice the buffer correctly on the server side.

```
const imageOne = fs.createReadStream('./image-1.jpg');
const imageTwo = fs.createReadStream('./image-2.jpg');

// This will be mixed, and you'll end up with a broken image
imageOne.on('data', chunk => client.sendBytes(chunk)); // add identifier
imageTwo.on('data', chunk => client.sendBytes(chunk)); // add identifier
```

The following is an example using [websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) package.

**Server**

```
/* rest of implementation */
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
  const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

  const JPEG_EOF = Buffer.from([0xFF, 0xD9]);
  let stream = null;

  connection.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.type === 'binary') {

      if(!stream) {
        stream = fs.createWriteStream(generateImageName())
         // this could be any Writable Stream
         // not necessarily a file stream.
         // It can be an HTTP request for example.
      }

      // Check if it's the end
      if(JPEG_EOF.compare(message.binaryData) === 0) {
        console.log('done');
        stream.end(message.binaryData);
        stream = null;
        return;
      }

      // You will need to implement a back pressure mechanism
      stream.write(message.binaryData)    
    }
  });
});
```

**Client**

```
/** ... **/
client.on('connect', function(connection) {

  fs.createReadStream('./some-image.jpg')
    .on('data', chunk => {
        connection.sendBytes(chunk);
    });

});
/** ... **/
```

The above example will only handle `jpeg` images, since it's checking directly against the last 2 bytes of a jpeg, you can implement the logic for other file types.

In the example I assume that you only stream 1 image at a time per connection, otherwise it will get mixed up.

Right now you need to implement a backpressure mechanism for `.write`, meaning that you have to check the return value and wait for the `drain` event. *I will submit an example with a custom `Readable stream` later on when I have more time, handling the backpressure correctly*

**UPDATE**

With the following snippet, since a `Readable` stream is implemented, we can use `.pipe` which will handle the backpressure.

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

class ImageStream extends Readable {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.chunks = [];
    this.EOF = Buffer.from([0xFF, 0xD9]);
  }

  add(chunk) {
    this.chunks.push(chunk);    

    if(this.isPaused()) {
      this.resume();

      // Need to call _read if instead of this.push('') you return without calling .push
      // this._read(); 
    }
  }

  _read() {

    const chunk = this.chunks.shift();

    if(!chunk) { // nothing to push, pause the stream until more data is added
      this.pause(); 
      return this.push(''); // check: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push
      // If you return without pushing
      // you need to call _read again after resume
    }

    this.push(chunk);

    // If the last 2 bytes are not sent in the same chunk
    // This won't work, you can implement some logic if that can happen
    // It's a really edge case.
    const last = chunk.slice(-2);
    if(this.EOF.compare(last) == 0)
      this.push(null); // Image done, end the stream.

  }
}

/* ... */
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
  const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

  let stream = null;

  connection.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.type === 'binary') {

      if(!stream) {
        stream = new ImageStream();
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(generateImageName()));
        // stream.pipe(request(/* ... */));
        stream.on('end', () => {
          stream = null; // done
        });
      }

      stream.add(message.binaryData);
    }
  });

  connection.on('close', function(connection) {
    // close user connection
  });
});
```